# Best way to avoid Out Of Memory errors - Android

Tags: android, multithreading, service, out-of-memory, handler

Currently, my group mates and I are making an android application that will help kids learn basic knowledge. It will have a teaching module and a quiz module for kids. I am having a problem with so much Out Of Memory errors popping up from the application.

The application always produces out of memory errors when, playing a music in the background, playing animations, switching between multiple images in the ImageSwitcher, and playing audio.I think my problem is disposing unused objects in my activities.

I have searched the internet so many times but i couldn't find an answer that solved our problem. Some other solutions are so complicated that I don't even understand them. Can anyone please help use prevent OOM errors when using components such as MediaPlayer, XML Animations, ImageSwtcher, and SoundPool? What should I use with each? Service? Thread? Handler? The ImageSwitcher is a headache, it goes off good at start, but when I was about to preview the 16th image in the list, the OOM error pops up.

Thanks for anyone who would help us. I will be glad to show our codes but it has so many comments and I think someone have the answer to this without our newbie codes. :)

Comment: 1. Android heap is limited.  2. Loaded images are stored on the heap. 3. Heap needed for an image is height x width x 4 bytes by default. 4. Don't try to keep 16 images loaded. 5. Use inscaling. 6. Google for 1-5.

Comment: Wow! thanks for the response. I will look for those.
Should i use ImageSwitcher for images? or is there any better approach?

What is best way of implementing sounds and music in android?

Answer (score 1):

1. Limit the scope of your variables
2. Do not forget to finish activities and do necessary cleanup upon destroy callback (clean listeners etc)
3. Learn a memory profiling tool such as Eclipse Mat part of Eclipse android dev tools. To find problems with your memory usage, see [debugging memory](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html)
4. Incorporate a image loading library in your code such as [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), to get a lot of boiler plate code for free and memory recycling

Comment: Sorry if would ask too many questions but how can i finish activities and do cleanup? I don't know what is your answer in number 3 and 4 but thanks. I will search for those.

Comment: @anonymous updated my answer with links. What I mean about the cleanup part is that there might be memory leaks in your code and (I haven't seen your code so I can't really tell) this usually happens when a Context (activity) or a listener etc is not freed upon exiting the activity (such cleanups usually is done in onPause or onDestroy, depending on the variable...)

Comment: Thanks sir. I will look over my codes and those links you gave. God bless you.